# How do I draw a filled Rectangular box on jpeg if given two pixels values like for eg:- pt1(0,0) and pt2(480, 240)?

Tags: go

I want to open a jpeg file from localdisk and draw a filled Rectangular box on it in Go, if i give two pixel points value like pt1(0,0) and pt2(480, 240)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://golang.org/pkg/image/jpeg/). You need to decode the image from JPEG, set the pixels in your rectangle to black, then re-encode to JPEG.

Here is a code example, it works if the image is in the same folder as the executable and you give the path like `myimg.jpg`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/jpeg"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    err := addBlackRectangle("myimg.jpg", 500, 500, 1000, 1000)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func addBlackRectangle(imgPath string, x1, y1, x2, y2 int) (err error) {
    r, err := os.Open(imgPath)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    img, err := jpeg.Decode(r)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    rect1 := img.Bounds()
    rect2 := image.Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    if !rect2.In(rect1) {
        err = fmt.Errorf("error: rectangle outside image")
        return
    }

    rgba := image.NewRGBA(rect1)
    for x := rect1.Min.X; x <= rect1.Max.X; x++ {
        for y := rect1.Min.Y; y <= rect1.Max.Y; y++ {
            p := image.Pt(x, y)
            if p.In(rect2) {
                rgba.Set(x, y, color.Black)
            } else {
                rgba.Set(x, y, img.At(x, y))
            }
        }
    }

    outputFile := "rect-" + imgPath
    w, err := os.Create(outputFile)
    defer w.Close()

    err = jpeg.Encode(w, rgba, nil)
    return
}
```